# Jquery Roundabout limiting items

Tags: jquery, carousel

I'm trying to find a way of limiting the items shown in Fred LeBlanc's Roundabout plugin. When you create a lot of items dynamically, the carousel can start to look very cramped.

Ideally I only want three items showing at once, the one in focus and the one to the left and to the right.

Only showing three items is the only way I can see to totally control the size of the carousel items exactly.

I've tried using a few different shapes (one of Freds other plugins to go with roundabout) and although the square shape gives me some success (only three items in view), the more and more items that are in the carousel, the items to the left and right get calculated smaller and smaller.

I've also tried hiding/showing items that go out of view/come into view to no avail. It's a sloppy way of doing things.

Comment: The roundabout shapes do not specify how much items are visible in the front. They are defining paths on which the images move around some center.